# Wake on WAN で Ubuntu が起動できない

Tags: ubuntu, network

#### 前提条件

同一セグメントでのWake on LANは成功している

##### 機器情報

- 起動させたいPC: Ubuntu 20.04
- ルーター: Aterm bl1000hw（NEC製）

#### やりたいこと、課題

外部からUbuntu 20.04を起動させたいが、現状は外部から起動できない

#### 質問内容

外部でもUbuntuを操作し、色々と開発したいと思い、WOLにたどり着きました。
現在WOLはできるのですが、WOWが出来ずに詰まっております。

グローバルIPアドレスは固定されていることを確認しております

##### ルーターの設定

ポートマッピング設定-NATエントリで、

- LAN側ホスト：192.168.0.255
  （ブロードバンドキャストアドレスが良いという記事を参考にし、このように設定しております）
- プロトコル：UDP
- ポート番号：any

Ubuntuのファイアウォール設定は22番と9番を許可にしており、外部からssh接続できることを確認済みです。

ssh接続できるため、外部からの接続は通っていると考えているのですが、これ以上何が原因がわからず、困っております。

不足している情報や、何かアドバイスございましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: WoLはブロードキャストでマジックパケット送信することで動作するので、同一サブネットに接続する必要があります。異なるサブネットからWoLする場合はVPN接続などでローカルLANに接続するなどの工夫が必要です。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。

結論としては解決いたしました。
原因はルータのMACアドレスを指定していた事でした。
（到達したいPCのMACアドレスを指定すると、起動することが出来ました）

また何かありましたら、コメント頂けますと幸いです。